# How to use .udl file in app.config file

Tags: c#

I had file as string.udl on my Desktop.which contain

[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbVisitorManagement;Data Source=SHREE-PC
 So I have to use this file for establishing connection in App.config file of My Project then what I have to do for this??

Comment: See http://connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to connect to ans Sqlserver cause of the SQLOLEDB.

In this case you have to remove the "Provider" from the file

F.E:

```
                string path = @"C:\YourFileName.udl";
                if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    string testfile = string.Empty;
                    try
                    {
                        testfile = File.ReadLines(path).Last();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // File is empty, handle exception
                    }
                    if (testfile != string.Empty)
                    {
                        var finalPath = tempfile.Remove(0, tempfile.IndexOf(';') + 1);
                        ConnectionString = finalPath;
           // Save ConnectionString to your App.config or do something else with it
                }
```

Also note that a *.udl is except in local networks a bad parctice cause the connectiondetails are visible for everyone.